# Why am I getting this error same thing works on my local machine but not in a container help me

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

Here is the error while running it in a docker container

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post error messages as formatted text, not as links to images of text. Or images of text. Is everything the same version in both environments?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with the version 17.5 of Node engine. You can try to downgrade your Docker image until it's resolved.

Please check the related GitHub issues before asking on StackOverflow,
[this one](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11377) seems to be your exact problem.